# Log In/Out Screen is Vertically Challenged on High Resolution

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

[image: Site background doesn't go to the bottom of the page.]

I'm using a 2560 x 1440 monitor and Chrome.  As you can see, the page background isn't quite able to fill the entire page.

Comment: Nothing to complaint about...

Comment: Wait... I was looking at the left and right sides of your screen... are you instead pointing out at the footer not extending all the way to the bottom?

Comment: This is why you always use a freehand circle. Or [point](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54377/what-does-weapons-are-easier-to-handle-mean)

Comment: @BenBrocka I was not aware of this pointing fad. From now on *all* my posts will feature pointing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce this issue in the current build of our network sites. If it remains a problem let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that you don't even need a ridiculously sized monitor/TV for this to happen. This also occurs on the much more sane 1920 x 1080 (24" 16:10 widescreen standard resolution for Windows)

[image]

Comment: Also, it is not limited to Chrome, but also Firefox.